# Reading from file, Batch

Tags: batch-file, read-write

I'm messing around in Batch and I'm wondering...

Can someone help me write to a file (`Doc1.txt` or `Doc1.doc`) then read it, set it to a variable. Changed and saved if needed? And have more then one password in a single file?

I've heard it's possible to read to a file, but I can't seem to get it work. I put the following.

```
FOR /F %i IN (Test1.txt) DO Echo %i
```

I get the error:

```
IN is not excepted at this time.
```

Any help will be loved. Thank you!

For example. Say I was making a log in thingy. Someone can create a new account, make a password, change it, etc etc.

Comment: You need to double the percents (`%` becomes `%%`) if used within a batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is relatively simple.
use the echo command, set /p, and the less than and greater than signes.

to save something to a file, do

```
echo %variablename%> Filename.extension
```

to read something from a file into a variable, do

```
set /p variablename= < filename.extension
```